# Как в Tkinter убрать крестик закрытия окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет!
Есть ли в Tkinter возможность убрать крестик закрытия окна?
Запретить изменение размеров окна ведь можно.
А можно ли запретить закрывать окно?

```
root.overrideredirect(1)
```

Этот вариант я знаю.
Но в нём есть один недостаток - при клике вне окна - окно пропадает.
И его иконки нет среди открытых программ на панели
Пример:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry('200x200')

# center
x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну или как сделать, чтобы окно не пропадало бесследно и было среди вкладок открытых программ?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Disable Exit (or \[ X \]) in tkinter Window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45467143/4279)

Answer (score 1):

сделать по верх остальных окон

```
root.lift()
root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',True)
```